# How to handle multiple environment support and different targets in a single project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a project with two targets: A and B.
A is the main application target and B is a share extension.

I have 4 environments for the app i.e, Debug, Dev, UAT and Release.

On the other hand, when the app is run in debug mode, it works fine. But, when i switch to Dev scheme - It run into error like unable to find dev.xconfig file for Dev and same happens for Uat environment as well.

So I update the build settings in B for pod related keys:
[image]

But then again the app runs into error of some or the other pod related imports as 'No such file present'

The application podfile looks like this :

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'A' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for A

  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'SwiftyChrono'
  pod 'Highcharts'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Drive'
  pod 'Giphy', :podspec => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/sdk.mobile.giphy.com/SDK/2.0.1/Giphy.podspec'
  pod 'WSTagsField'  
  pod 'NewRelicAgent'
end


  target 'B' do
    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!
    # Pods for 'B'
    pod 'NewRelicAgent'

end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

On pod install I also get waring like:
`` [!] The `A [Debug UAT]` target overrides the `PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-A/Pods-A.debug uat.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or - Remove the build settings from the target. ``

I tried adding `$(inherited)` code in  taget 'B' of the podfile but again ran into error.

It would be of great help, If i get some help out here.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by following the instructions of updating pod settings in build settings for `target 'B'` as below and it worked for me.
`PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR , PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH, PODS_ROOT, USE_RECURSIVE_SCRIPT_INPUTS_IN_SCRIPT_PHASES, PODS_BUILD_DIR = $(inhertied)`.

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
  platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'A' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for A

  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.9.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 6.14'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 6.14'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'SwiftyChrono'
  pod 'Highcharts' #, '~> 7.0.1'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Drive', '~> 1.3.7'
  pod 'Giphy', :podspec => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/sdk.mobile.giphy.com/SDK/2.0.1/Giphy.podspec'
  pod 'WSTagsField'
  pod 'NewRelicAgent', '~> 5.14.2'
  
  target 'B' do
     # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
     use_frameworks!
   end

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```